# Why does the REPLICATE function reevaluate the value of NEWID when passed into a function that returns a table?

Tags: sql-server

I wrote this function, and then went to test it. The results kind of surprised me. Any idea why this happens?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.chunk(@input VARCHAR(MAX), @chunkSize INT = 36)

RETURNS TABLE AS    

RETURN (

    WITH CTE AS (

        SELECT SUBSTRING(@input,1,@chunkSize) AS [chunk], 1 AS [row]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT SUBSTRING(@input,1+([row]*@chunkSize),@chunkSize)
        , [row] + 1 
        FROM cte
        WHERE LEN(@input) > ([row]*@chunkSize)  

    )

    SELECT [chunk] 
    FROM cte

)

GO
```

```sql
/* This does what I would expect this to do. */
DECLARE @input varchar(MAX) = REPLICATE(NEWID(),2);
SELECT * FROM dbo.chunk(@input,36)

/* But this, this is odd. If I call replicate here it calls newid() twice... */
SELECT * FROM dbo.chunk(REPLICATE(NEWID(),2),36);
```

| chunk |
| --- |
| E1810B3D-3DD4-4F55-B650-ED2DB28BCF70 |
| E1810B3D-3DD4-4F55-B650-ED2DB28BCF70 |

| chunk |
| --- |
| 89A26C8B-D5C7-47A8-BBBC-FE859B24E267 |
| F9636F76-1ED6-4D19-A309-BA35EAC9F782 |

Comment: NewID() is a non deterministic function.   It is re-evaluated every time is it called

Comment: Why would the first replicate be different from the second?

Comment: Ah, I see your question now

Comment: A simpler version of the problem (it is not about recursive CTE's, just when/how the `newid` function is evaluated): `create function dbo.chunk(@input varchar(max), @chunkSize int = 36) returns table as return select substring(@input,1,@chunkSize) + '/' + substring(@input,@chunkSize+1,@chunkSize+1) as [row];
`

Comment: Without being an expert, I'd say just that the function is being evaluated at runtime in the later case, during the execution phase, whereas in the first case it is (clearly) being evaluated before and completely independently of the `chunk` function. You can also see the difference in execution plans. In general, it is just wise to be careful with non-deterministic functions (this is yet another example of how they deserve their name and reputation).

Comment: Remember too that you are creating a table valued function - so the behavior is akin to using newid() in a query. You might create a multi-step table valued function to get the "newid being called once" behavior - but of course tvp's and mtvp's are two quite different kinds of functions that return table values.

Comment: For those interested, here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LiNLVHaU). (corrected)

Comment: It's nothing to do with replicate. It is just how inlined TVFs and non deterministic functions interact. Simpler example https://dbfiddle.uk/K6zS5FZJ - note NEWID() appears four times in the execution plan despite the function referencing the same parameter name `@input` four times

Comment: `NEWID` does weird stuff compared to other non-determinnistic functions: it is always called on each row even if there is only one reference. Compare to `RAND` and `GETDATE` which does not usually, although TVFs and `APPLY` might be an exception

Comment: Why would the first replicate be different from the second? - because the second has two rows

Answer (score 0):

This is very expected.

The function you are using is an inline table valued function so the call is inlined into the general execution plan.

The function has `@input` parameter of type `VARCHAR(MAX)` and you are passing `REPLICATE(NEWID(),2)` to it so conceptually just

- replace all instances of `@input` in your function with `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),REPLICATE(NEWID(),2))`.
- Similarly just replace all instances of `@chunkSize` with 36.

Once you do that you end up with the below which gives an identical execution plan and behaviour.

```
WITH CTE AS (

    SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),REPLICATE(NEWID(),2)),1,36) AS [chunk], 1 AS [row]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),REPLICATE(NEWID(),2)),1+([row]*36),36)
    , [row] + 1 
    FROM cte
    WHERE LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),REPLICATE(NEWID(),2))) > ([row]*36)  

)

SELECT [chunk] 
FROM cte
```

`NEWID()` is referenced in the plan three times. Once in the anchor branch of the recursive CTE and twice in the recursive branch. In your case you get one invocation of the anchor and one invocation of the recursive branch so it is evaluated three times. For the expression involving the `LEN` the re-evaluation doesn't make any difference to the result as the length will be the same even if the actual guid has changed.

Some non deterministic functions are treated as [runtime constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112013248/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions/) but `NEWID()` is not one of them. That doesn't really help you in this recursive CTE case anyway.

If you try the following...

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.RandRows(@input float, @Rows INT = 10)
RETURNS TABLE AS    
RETURN (
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT 1 AS Level, @input as [rand]
        WHERE @Rows >= 1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Level + 1, @input as [rand]
        FROM cte
        WHERE @Rows > Level + 1  
    )
    SELECT [rand] 
    FROM cte
)

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.RandRows(RAND(), 10)
```

It ends up the same as

```
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT 1 AS Level, rand() as [rand]
        WHERE 10 >= 1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Level + 1, rand() as [rand]
        FROM cte
        WHERE 10 > Level + 1  
    )
    SELECT [rand] 
    FROM cte
```

The invocation in the anchor branch and recursive branches are treated as two different invocations and given different runtime constant labels so you get [one value in the first row and a different value in the subsequent rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/ONaJkzhw).